# pivot and unpivot sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I currently have tables like the following:

```
Check 1:
Name        |Q1|Q2|Q3|Q4
----------- |--|--|--|--
McDonalds   | P| P| F| P
Burger King | F| P| P| F

Check 2:
Name        |Q1|Q2|Q3|Q4
----------- |--|--|--|--
McDonalds   | F| F| F| P
Burger King | F| P| P| P
```

I would like to unpivot on Q1-Q4, so that I get a single column named 'Quarter'. I would also like to combine the two (or more) tables with new columns pertaining to the check, e.g.:

```
Name        |Quarter|Check 1|Check 2
------------|-------|-------|-------
McDonalds   |     Q1|      P|      F
McDonalds   |     Q2|      P|      F
McDonalds   |     Q3|      F|      F
McDonalds   |     Q4|      P|      P
Burger King |     Q1|      F|      F
Burger King |     Q2|      P|      P
Burger King |     Q3|      P|      P
Burger King |     Q4|      F|      P
```

I found a way to unpivot the tables on the quarter columns via the following:

```
SELECT Name, Quarter, PassFail
FROM Check1
unpivot
(
  PassFail
  for Quarter in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
) u
```

But I haven't been able to combine the two steps. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit** I am using Microsoft SQL Sever 2012

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen. I m using MS SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to repeat your `UNPIVOT` on each table and `JOIN` the results:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.Check2
FROM (SELECT Name, Quarter, Check1
      FROM CheckTable1
      UNPIVOT
       (
        Check1
        for Quarter in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
       ) u
     ) T1
JOIN (SELECT Name, Quarter, Check2
      FROM CheckTable2
      UNPIVOT
        (
          Check2
          for Quarter in (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
        ) u
      ) T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
          AND T1.QUARTER = T2.QUARTER
```